# Send a react native container through the bridge for native code to display an image

Tags: android, c++, ios, react-native

I'm writing a react native application that is bridged with cross platform C++ code that produces images.

I'd like to send a container component from React Native to the C++ code to display the image that is a byte array.

Is that even possible ?

All the images component I've seen so far just work with an image on the file system and/or an URI. In my case, I do not want to save the images to the internal storage.

Or maybe there is a clever way ?

EDIT 1 : The native side stores an image in memory in a byte array.

EDIT 2 : to prevent large data moving native C++ to react native, I want the RN side to the tell the native side where to draw the image.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "sending a container component"? Do you have the image data in JS and want to send it over the RN bridge to the native side? Or do you already have an Image component showing in JSX and you want to locate and access it from the native code?

Comment: I have an image on native side, that I would display in a container brougth to me by the RN side. The only way around would be to the RN side to display an image coming in raw byte array

Comment: It's still not so clear to me where do you store the image data, or where do you get it from. It would be very inefficient to move large amounts of binary data over the RN bridge. If your intention is to access a specific native view there's a way to do it by passing its react node handle to the native side

Comment: Where we get the image data is outside the scope of the question which I have edited.